# Any way to fix old rusted utility sink drain?

Tags: plumbing, drain, sink

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wce5V.jpg

My old (1940) house has a basement utility sink that has started to leak at the drain (shown in picture). Is there a way to replace the section that is rusted or do I have to rip the whole thing out and replace it? It looks like its a very different mechanism to modern utility sinks, it doesn't have a threaded base or a threaded drain strainer (just a hole). How do I go about fixing this?

Edit: From some googling, this is an old concrete tub and weighs and absolute ton.

Edit: I decided to have a professional plumber look at this and he ran water in the sink for a minute and he could see that the concrete itself was weeping a bit, so it was worth demolishing the sink and installing a new plastic one. He just took a sledgehammer to it, loaded it in a few buckets on his truck, and installed the new sink in a couple hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much you're going to be able to do with that. Your best bet will be to start removing the whole drain piece, clean up the concrete and then try to match the drain with something similar from a plumbing supple store. Good luck.

Comment: I think the drain piece is cast into the cement. Would I just get the old drain out using a dremel? If so, how on earth would I add a new drain?

Comment: Those flanges underneath look removable although totally rusted. A dremel with a cutoff wheel would do the trick. Wear eye protection and I'd also use one of those breathing masks. Once you clear that out, you can better judge what to do next.

Comment: One time I ground on some iron without a dust mask, and later unrelated, I cut myself pretty bad.  I asked the doctor "why am I bleeding red?" Doctor said "it is the iron in your blood".  Wore a dust mask after that! ;-)